# How to avoid BAD SELECTOR errors when using @selector( ) for known targets

Tags: objective-c, ios

One of the more common errors I make when programming in Xcode is bad selectors, whether due to renaming or refactoring or mistyping. They can't be avoided as many functions use SEL parameters, like button targets.

They are NOT detected during the build, so everything seems fine until you get a runtime crash.

1. Since the majority of selectors used are known when you're coding it, don't need to dynamic, is there a better way to specify an SEL instead of just using @selector()?
2. If not, is there at least a way to format @selector() in a way that CAN at least be checked by the compiler at build time?

Thanks all!

---

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    UIButton* buttonBroken = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(100, 50, 100, 44)];
    [buttonBroken addTarget: self action:@selector(theWrongFunction) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self addSubview: buttonBroken];
}

- (void)theRightFunction
{
    // Everything compiled without warning or issues, but I never got a call :(
}
```

Comment: Have you tried editing project build settings? Choose to display all settings, filter by 'warn' and in Objective-C section enable warnings with regard to selectors. They are disabled by default.

Comment: Thanks Piotr, the UNDECLARED_SELECTOR setting may catch some potential issues. But, if ANY function with the same name was declared prior to evaluating the @selector, the compiler still passes over it without warnings. Even if declared in a completely unrelated class or imported library! Maybe a good workaround is to try and choose very unique selector names, and hope they are verbose enough to not to have ever been used elsewhere, but that goes against convention and consistency.

Comment: Well, for one thing...you could stop changing your function names around so much.  The first time you type it, it should autocomplete.  After that, don't change it without using the refactor tool.  This will warn you about the selector being used as well (but it won't change it automatically)

Comment: Write functional tests :) versify that on click of the button the code you expect executes.